# como receber valores de panel para um array de strings?

Tags: delphi

como receber valores de panel com edits para um array de strings?
preciso que 10 registros que vão ser digitados em edits que estão dentro de um panel, e assim salvar num array de strings ou inteiros.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure Form1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject)
var
  //declaro o array
  valores: array of string;
begin
  //Altero a quantidade de items do array, no caso 10.
  SetLength(valores, 10);

  //Passo o valor dos edits para os itens do array
  //NOTA: Arrays começam pelo índice 0. No nosso caso os itens do nosso array
  //vão de 0 até 9.
  valores[0] := Edit1.Text;
  valores[1] := Edit2.Text;
  ...
  valores[9] := Edit10.Text;
end;
```

Comment: Adiciona uma explicação textual para que sua resposta também seja útil ao outros membros.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique adicionado ;)